# So I cant get these cards right. these images and cards are changing in size whenever I insert a <h> with more text, the more text the more changes

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Here is an example

[image: Example on my problem]

here is my code

```
<div className="lg:flex gap-10 mx-auto">
    <div className="text-center shadow-lg p-10 rounded-xl my-10 border-4 border-teal-600 flex-auto   items-center">
        <Image src={figma1} width={"100%"} height={"100%"} layout="responsive" className="rounded-xl border-teal-600" />
        <div className="text-center shadow-lg p-10 rounded-xl my-1 flex-auto items-center">
            <h3 className="text-lg font-medium pt-8 pb-2">Less text smaller picture</h3>
            <button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Vis</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Im using tailwind.

I dont know how to fix this. Ive tried overflow-hidden- h-full etc, but cant seem to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `width={"100%"} height={"100%"}`, and the text is making the container bigger, so it's logical that the 100% will be bigger when the container is bigger because the text is bigger. If you don't want that, you can just change the width and height using a fixed width, and not a width with %, that follows the change in the container.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it, now the images wont affect the cards. But the text is. Do I need to add fixed width to the text aswell? Ive tried but I cant seem to find a solution to it still.

Comment: I'm happy that I could help, please select my answer as the solution. About the width of the cards, if you don't want them to be "flexible", so you maybe don't want to use flex, or as an easy solution, you can add a fixed width and height to the container of them too.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `margin:0` for the h3 tags. Since `<h>` tags have a default margin to them. You have to set them to 0 manually

```
.text-center h3{
margin :0
}
```